# How can I match the second array based on the first array?

Tags: c#

How can I identify the first and closest date index in the second array between two indexes from the source array?
I put an example of test data from two arrays below

Long_Array,
Short_Array

```
Long_Array :            Short_Array
index   date            index   date
0   20180101            0   20170906
1   20180605            1   20171218
2   20181115            2   20180112
3   20190225            3   20180216
4   20190714            4   20180425
5   20200321            5   20180520
6   20210110            6   20180603
                        7   20180721
                        8   20180817
```

For example, the two indices of the source array are 0 and 1
And the desired output in the second array is index 2 and 6

This is the code I wrote, but it has a problem

```
int indexFrom = Array.FindIndex(Short_Array, row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Date) >= Convert.ToInt32(Long_Array[i].Date));
int indexTo = Array.FindIndex(Short_Array, row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Date) < Convert.ToInt32(Long_Array[i + 1].Date));
```

Comment: The efficient way to do this would be to use a sorted list and [`BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-6.0). The trick is to figure out the correct comparison algorithm for these magic integers that do not represent integers. You probably need to convert them to dates.

Comment: I converted the date to a number so it can be used

Answer (score 0):

I would write it explicitly

1. Select all the in between
2. Find the closest
3. Optimise from there if necessary.

```
long[] first, second;

long[] GetClosest(int idx1, int idx2)
{
    var x = second.Select(i => new { v = i, d1 = i - first[idx1], d2 = first[idx2] - i }).Where(i => i.d1 >= 0 && i.d2 >= 0).ToArray();
            
    if(x.Length == 0) return new long[0];

    var x1 = x.First(k => k.d1 == x.Min(i => i.d1)).v;
    var x2 = x.First(k => k.d2 == x.Min(i => i.d2)).v;

    return new long[] { Array.IndexOf(second, x1), Array.IndexOf(second, x1) };
        
}
```